# C# design for handling a high rate of async network operations that complete with a callback (hundreds per second)

Tags: c#, async, event-handling

I am working with a message broker technology, to which events will be published (following an "event carried state transfer" architecture) for consumption by other applications.

The vendor library uses a pattern where a message is handed to a `Session` object defined by the vendor's client library code, which sends it over the network to the broker, and the vendor's client code will call an `OnSessionEvent` method which includes data in the event args indicating whether the message was successfully published to the broker. A message may be initially accepted by the `Session` object but fail to be published to the broker if, for example, the broker's buffer is full (typically a temporary state of affairs).

It could easily be the case that the original source of events is raising them at the rate of up-to-thousands of messages a second.

To further complicate matters, it may be the case that multiple different event sources may be publishing to the same `Session`, and so the `OnSessionEvent` response needs to be routed back to the appropriate publisher.

In any case, my struggle right now is trying to figure out an appropriate pattern to efficiently send messages and handle the callbacks. It would of course be less than ideal to send a single message and then wait for the callback result before sending the next message, since the network response may take several milliseconds.

I could create a `Task` for each message send attempt, collect up a bunch of these tasks, and wait on them as a batch of, say, 100. This is clearly faster than one-message-at-a-time. However it would mean generating hundreds or possibly up to thousands of `Tasks` every second. Note that the vendor code does not natively expose the network operation as an `async` operation using a `Task`. In order to use this pattern, I would add a `TaskCompletionSource` object to the (local) message object, and `SetResult` on that `TaskCompletionSource` when the (local) message object is made available via the callback argument. I am concerned about the rate of object construction that this could cause.

I am hoping for advice or articles which talk about situations like this. I am also curious as to the threading implications of asynchronous callbacks, so a comment or article that covers both would be idea.

Comment: Object construction rates?  It is most likely the network that will be your bottleneck regardless of what you do.

Comment: Well, the interface does not require that I process messages in series. I could, if I so chose, send a thousand messages to the vendor `Session` and ignore the callback entirely. Or I could send a thousand messages, accumulate the responses, and process all of those responses at once. Or I could send a message and wait for the response before sending the next. In the third case, the network is certainly the bottleneck. But that does not seem to be trivially the case for the first two options. It would depend on message size and network bandwidth.

Comment: If the original source is bursting at thousands per second, do you need to immediately meet that need?  Or, can you tolerate an in-memory buffer to absorb the burst while your messaging sends at a more consistent hundreds-per-second rate?

Comment: That's a good question - is the mesage rate "bursty". I don't think I can answer that question universally, although I would say that a rate of thousands per second is unlikely to be continuous over, say, hours. The pragmatic approach that I am trying to follow is to come up with a solution that is at least not "lazily" inefficient.  In other words, generating several hundred task objects per second might be strictly acceptable in some case, but if an approach exists which is fundamentally more efficient without introducing greatly more complexity, it would of course be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't yet have enough information to post a full answer, but I will start and hopefully refine it with input.

I would start out by, first of all, not assuming creating Tasks will be slow.  They are designed explicitly to be fast.  There is an entire mechanism inside of .NET to make them fast, and the language designers and other domain experts have told us Task is fast.

https://gist.github.com/mgravell/878e7fb19ad2378941f810820b9e90b5:

```
                                       Method |          Mean |     StdDev |       Op/s | Scaled | Scaled-StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
--------------------------------------------- |--------------:|-----------:|-----------:|-------:|--------------:|-------:|----------:|
                               int/await/task | 4,808.1011 ns | 34.5216 ns |  207982.32 |   6.70 |          0.05 | 3.4438 |  21.61 kB |
                  int/manual/task/iscompleted | 2,490.7947 ns | 24.4512 ns |  401478.29 |   3.47 |          0.04 | 3.4786 |  21.82 kB |
      int/manual/task/iscompletedsuccessfully | 2,987.2058 ns | 25.0176 ns |     334761 |   4.16 |          0.04 | 3.4781 |  21.82 kB |
                          int/await/valuetask | 5,395.7703 ns | 27.8437 ns |  185330.35 |   7.52 |          0.05 |      - |      0 kB |
             int/manual/valuetask/iscompleted |   702.5910 ns |  4.0544 ns | 1423303.24 |   0.98 |          0.01 |      - |      0 kB |
 int/manual/valuetask/iscompletedsuccessfully |   702.9448 ns |  2.4655 ns | 1422586.73 |   0.98 |          0.01 |      - |      0 kB |
                                     int/sync |   717.4125 ns |  3.0914 ns | 1393898.17 |   1.00 |          0.00 |      - |      0 kB |
```

https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-does-task-in-c-affect-performance.html:

> This processed the same number of records: 5000. The "Manhattan Classifier" took 164 seconds to complete, so it was a little bit faster. But the "Null Classifier" took no time at all (well, less than a second).
> At first, I thought I may have taken out a bit too much code. Maybe the continuations weren't really running. But each record was processed, and we can see that the error count is the same as before: 4515. The error count is incremented in the continuation, so I knew that was still running.

I created a test program on my laptop to start a million tasks and wait for them to no-op finish.  It took 4 seconds.  So, my benchmark for performance is 250,000 tasks/sec, which is 2-3 orders of magnitude faster than you need so far.  So, it could just be a case of "don't worry about it, and code what's easiest".  The code is as follows (the 5 second delay for "booting" is because my Visual Studio likes to fling its windows around as it starts up and I wanted it to finish that nonsense):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("booting");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("go");
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var tasks = new List<Task>(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
                .Select(i => Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Task.Yield().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                })));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

booting
go
4726
```

Comment: That is a useful metric, but if the task is literally performing a no-op then it will be executed synchronously and avoid much of the overhead of tasks, and so the rate is perhaps not illustrative. But in terms of pure cost of object creation (and perhaps collection - though this might require a long-running test), I agree that it is indicative. This is, in fact, the approach of the code I have as currently written, and to your previous question, I do "buffer" a collection of these tasks and wait on them to complete, introducing a small amount of latency for greater overall efficiency.

Comment: I'll update my post with my sample code.  I'm not strictly no-op'ing, I'm actually doing a Task.Yield (which is the overhead with async/await)

Comment: That is enough for me to believe that using a task wrapper around each async callback is acceptable for any situation that I would encounter in my environment - and that my code is currently written using this approach reflects my expectation that this would be the case (I performed a similar test a while ago). I think this still leaves open the question as to whether this is a "good" approach - in the sense that another approach may exist that is similarly simple and strictly more efficient. But I concede that "good enough" is fundamental in engineering.

Comment: I understand the itchiness around code not being as optimal as possible.  Keep your algorithm solid, defer behavior to injected interfaces, and rewrite this part down the line if it doesn't keep up.